# Date parsing. How do I parse this date format?

Tags: android, date, date-parsing

How do I parse this date format:

> "/Date(1514728800000+0300)/"

I don't know what the meaning of this number is, or that of the `+` sign.

Comment: where you get these values?

Comment: From a web service which I don't have access to and can not change

Comment: no idea about +0300 may be timezone or something.

Comment: The first part (1514728800000) is a [unix timestamp](https://www.unixtimestamp.com) - the number of milliseconds since unix epoch (`1970-01-01T00:00Z`). The second part (`+0300`) is an [UTC offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset), it represents the difference from UTC (in this case, 3 hours ahead UTC). But what should be the result of parsing? A `java.util.Date`? Any other object?

Comment: @Hugo It seems weird to me that one would add a UTC offset to a Unix timestamp. I thought one of the purposes of Unix timestamps was to avoid the hassle with time zones. (Not saying you're wrong, in fact you're probably right. It's just seems a weird decision by the web service in question).

Comment: @S.L.Barth I also think it's strange, but my guess is that you can convert the timestamp to the specified offset, so you'll get a specific date and time (as the same timestamp corresponds to a different date and time in each timezone). But I still think it's not the smartest format...

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer: the number is the [epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

This is the amount of seconds since Jan 1, 1970, UTC.
You can pass this value to the constructor of [java.util.Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), which will get you a `Date` object with the right value.

The +0300 is unclear, perhaps a reference to a different timezone.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure about the +0300, but you can convert a epoch time to Date with the following function:

```
 Date date = new Date(Long.parseLong(myDateToParse.replaceAll("[^\\d-]", "")));
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: This will create a `long` value equals to `15147288000000300`, but the last digits (`0300`) are not part of the millis value and it shouldn't be passed to `Date` constructor (your code creates a date in year **481968**!) - you should pass just `1514728800000`. And `Locale.DEFAULT` doesn't exist, perhaps you meant `Locale.getDefault()`?

Comment: @Hugo True, i meant Locale.getDefault(), thanks for the input. As for the +0300, i also have to say taht you are right. What i tried to do in my example, was to parse a simple epoch time (without the +0300). You could just simplly remove the +0300 and add the 3 Hours (with the required logic) to the new Date

Comment: Well, you can always [edit] your answers to fix/improve them, if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that parses this assuming you have *unixtimestamp_zoneoffset*

```
String inputStr = "1514728800000+0300";
String[] splitStr = inputStr.split("[+-]");
String offsetSign = inputStr.indexOf("+")>0 ? "+" : "-";
ZonedDateTime captureTime = Instant.ofEpochMilli(Long.valueOf(splitStr[0])).atZone(ZoneOffset.of(offsetSign+splitStr[1]));
```

The value returned is *2017-12-31T17:00+03:00*